# BouncyCastle GCM/CCM ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

can anyone give me an example for using GCM and/or CCM modes with AES in BouncyCastle?
My code is this:

```
SecretKeySpec   key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
Cipher          cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
byte[] block = new byte[1048576];
int i;
long st,et;

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

BufferedInputStream bIn=new BufferedInputStream(new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null,"Encrypting ...",new FileInputStream("input")));
CipherInputStream       cIn = new CipherInputStream(bIn, cipher);
BufferedOutputStream bOut=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.enc"));

int ch;
while ((i = cIn.read(block)) != -1) {
    bOut.write(block, 0, i);
}
cIn.close();
bOut.close();

Thread.sleep(5000);

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

BufferedInputStream fis=new BufferedInputStream(new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null,"Decrypting ...",new FileInputStream("output.enc")));
//FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("output.enc");
//FileOutputStream ro=new FileOutputStream("regen.plain");
BufferedOutputStream ro=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("regen.plain"));

CipherInputStream dcIn = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);

while ((i = dcIn.read(block)) != -1) {
        ro.write(block, 0, i);
}

dcIn.close();
ro.close();
```

but it throws this exception when decrypting in GCM mode (line 70 is `bOut.write(block, 0, i);`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CCMBlockCipher.processPacket(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CCMBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(DashoA13*..)
    at enctest.Main.main(Main.java:70)
```

And this Exception when encrypting in CCM mode (line 70 is `bOut.write(block, 0, i);`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CCMBlockCipher.processPacket(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CCMBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(DashoA13*..)
    at enctest.Main.main(Main.java:70)
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken about what line 70 is. Is it not `while ((i = cIn.read(block)) != -1)`?

Comment: @DuncanJones: no it is the `.write` line!

Answer (score 7):

For CCM mode there is a little snag: the size of the IV should be smaller than the block size. Your code crashes on the following:

```
BlockCipher ctrCipher = new SICBlockCipher(cipher);
byte[] iv = new byte[blockSize];
byte[] out;

iv[0] = (byte)(((15 - nonce.length) - 1) & 0x7);

System.arraycopy(nonce, 0, iv, 1, nonce.length);
```

Try it with an "IV" of 15 bytes instead (the IV is actually a NONCE, but `IvParameterSpec` is used for the NONCE).

The other problem is that the `cipher.doFinal()` method is both called when `CipherInputStream` cannot retrieve any data from the underlying stream, as well as when `close()` is called. Note that `CipherInputStream` is a very badly written class that also removes `BadPaddingException` when it is thrown - this is the exception you get when the tag validation fails (!!!). You are better off creating your own one based on `CipherInputStream`. I've changed to the code to throw specific `IOException` based exceptions instead of ignoring exceptions, and keeping a `boolean` state to see if `doFinal()` has been executed on the underlying cipher. It should not call `doFinal()` twice.

So you are running in a Java JCE bug here. I might put it in the Oracle bug database, where it not that up till now all my bug reports have been ignored completely.

Tested against latest version of OpenJDK 7 and Bouncy Castle 1.47 (2012-08-30 or something close).

Comment: If you remove the close call, then the code should run, but you would not get any authentication, which was kind of the point.